# Dynamic Conditional Formatting in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on an engineering program that has all it's calculations written in VB.net in a separate project and we are now putting it behind a WPF UI.

I've run into an issue with changing String Formats between units. For example: In Imperial Units you have a value of 4,966 lbf and converted it's 22.1 kN. You can see that it is necessary to have a different format between the 2 as they are different orders of magnitude.

What is currently set up in the program is conditional coloring (black for normal number, red for error, yellow for warning) these are set up through styles in a resource dictionary.

```
<Style x:Key="GlobalUserEditedTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="TextBox">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource EditableTextColor}"/>
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="GlobalErrorTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="TextBox">
     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ErrorTextColor}"/>
     <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
</Style>
```

In the program the style is chosen using a Converter and  MultiBinding. `ValueShow.TensionStatusShow` is an enum value coming out of the VB calculation code:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=ValueShow.TensionShow}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource styleConverter}">
            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="ValueShow.TensionStatusShow"/>
            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

And then the MultiValueConverter:

```
public class StyleConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            FrameworkElement targetElement = values[0] as FrameworkElement;
            Style _newStyle;
            try
            {
                if (values[1] == null || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                    return null;

                if ((String)values[1] == StatusColor.ErrorValue.ToString())
                {
                    if (values[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                        _newStyle = (Style)targetElement.TryFindResource("GlobalErrorTextBox");
                    else if (values[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
                        _newStyle = (Style)targetElement.TryFindResource("GlobalErrorTextBlock");
                    else
                        _newStyle = null;
                } 
                else if
                {
                    if (values[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                        _newStyle = (Style)targetElement.TryFindResource("GlobalWarningTextBox");
                    else if (values[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
                        _newStyle = (Style)targetElement.TryFindResource("GlobalWarningTextBlock");
                    else
                        _newStyle = null;
                }
                return _newStyle;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (values[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                    return (Style)targetElement.TryFindResource("GlobalUnEditableTextBox");
                else if (values[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
                    return (Style)targetElement.TryFindResource("GlobalUnEditableTextBlock");
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

**What I've tried:**
So the problem here is that I want to keep the string formatting "rules" out of the VB calculation methods unlike `ValueShow.TensionStatusShow`. Currently we have 2 resource Dictionaries (Imperial and Metric) that hold the strings for unit labels. I've tried setting up the different string formats there so it will update when the program changes units.

Imperial Resource:

```
<s:String x:Key="UnitsStringFormatlbfkN">F0</s:String>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="GlobalErrorTextBoxlbkNFormatting" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlobalErrorTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={StaticResource UnitsStringFormatlbfkN}}" />
    </Style>
```

Metric Resource

```
<s:String x:Key="UnitsStringFormatlbfkN">F1</s:String>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="GlobalErrorTextBoxlbkNFormatting" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlobalErrorTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={StaticResource UnitsStringFormatlbfkN}}" />
    </Style>
```

Then I would pass `lbkNFormatting` as a third parameter in the multibinding and append it to the `TryFindResource`call. This apparently didn't work though, It would successfully load the resource but it ignored the string format. I tested by adding background colors to the Metric resource which loaded fine, but again, the string format was ignored.

I also tried modifying the style in the MultiValueConverter by programatically adding the string formatting but ran into the `IsSealed` property which I can't seem to defeat

Comment: Did you try changing StringFormat to a DynamicResource instead of static?

Comment: I just tried and I get the following error: A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'StringFormat' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for quick&short&not full and indirect response, but I wanted to drop you an often overlooked solution. I sometimes use it when some binding or styling gets too complex and starts failing and seems impossible to trace why, or when I see that I could benefit from extra decoupling.

Almost all styles, triggers and complex bindings+MultiValueCoverters, you can rewrite into so-called "Attached behavior".

[See this article](http://briannoyes.net/2012/12/20/attached-behaviors-vs-attached-properties-vs-blend-behaviors/) for some quick glance. Note the two ways, attached properties and extra subelements.

Actually, I like to use the best of both at the same time. Since I wanted to just drop you a note, I've trimmed this answer and moved chatty text to [this article](http://quetzalcoatl-pl.blogspot.com/2015/01/quick-reminder-about-attachedproperties.html).

I know this does not answer to your question about why the Style&Binding does not work, but I still think you may find it helpful. Your styles and bindings seem complex enough to be hard to debug, and I can't focus on that currently :| The problem is that bindings can be very easily broken (detached, overridden) by trying to put a value on wrong scope/level, and even the setters from styles and triggers can unlink them from targets. I sense that this is what's happening, but I won't have more time to help you trace it in near future. So.. good luck and I hope someone manages to give you a better response.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a very useful feature. I'd never heard of Attached Behavior, but it sounds like it should help out a lot with the issues we've been running into trying to have dynamic styles.

Comment: So I've set up the 3 properties (SourceValue, Units, and DisplayValue) all within the static class `AttachedValue` but I am having issues with the binding on the text. `Text="{Binding (AttachedValue.DisplayValue), RelativeSource=Self}"` Compiler complains it cant find AttchedValue and when it runs there is an error with the relative source trying to cast a String to a Relative Source. Do you know what might be going on or should I update my code to look at?

Comment: @user3565590: I was writing from memory. Try `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` instead. About `(AttachedValue.DisplayedValue)` binding, try prefixing it with namespace prefix, i.e. `(myns:AttachedValue.DisplayedValue)`, replace `myns` with the correct prefix for your namespace. If that does not work, try adding explicit Path attribute, that is: `Fooo="{Binding Path=(myns:AttachedValue.DisplayedValue), ..."` it helps when WPF cannot figure out how to parse the expression, it happens sometimes.

Comment: So adding the namespace and RelativeSource fixed the compile issues and it runs, but I'm not getting the `GetDisplayValue` funciton to be called. I have a feeling it has to do with the `my:AutoUnitConversion`function you have attached. You mentioned that in the post but I'm not exactly sure whit it is/supposed to be doing. Is that supposed to be a method in the static class `AttachedValue` that takes all the properties and computes a string to give back to the xaml?

Comment: @user3565590: after attaching and binding the `UnitSource` and `SourceValue` properties, and creating `DisplayValue` property, you got the basic data links. Now you need something that will actually perform the job: something must watch for the UnitSource and SourceValue changes, and when such change occurs, that something must calculate-what-you-want and then set the DisplayedValue. There's really no free lunch out there. You  have two choices

Comment: @user3565590: (1) at place where you create/register the UnitSource&SourceValue depprops, you can add `Metadata` to the properties' definitions. This allows to add a `ValueChanged` event handler to that property. In that handler you can get the target DependencyObject (->TextBlock) and the values of all interesting properties from it (->UnitSource,SourceValue) and then do the job and set DisplayValue on that TextBlock. [See here how to set ChangedHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The code is for plain depprop, but it's similar for attached.

Comment: Apparently I already thought of the solution and had it commented out, I had a function listening to both setters and when both were set it updated the `DisplayValue`. For some reason it doesn't hit the break point in the `GetDisplayValue` but it does update the text to the UI. Thanks for walking me through that!

Comment: @user3565590: (2) instead of cluttering the dep-props registration code, don't add handlers there but use a `Behavior`. [See this article](http://briannoyes.net/2012/12/20/attached-behaviors-vs-attached-properties-vs-blend-behaviors/) for an example. Section `Blend Behaviors` shows an example of `ItemClickNavBehavior2 : Behavior<..>` that is a "tag' usable in XAML, attachable to GridView. This Behavior class comes with Attach method that is called whenever a behavior gets attached to a GridView, and in this Attach you can inject your bidnings/handlers/logic to that GridView. Or TextBlock.

Comment: @user3565590: As for the `GetDisplayValue` not being hit, that's because it .. is not even executed. Setting/Getting all DependencyProperties, both attached and normal, are mostly internally handled by WPF. It's the WPF that stores that values for you in some smart hashmaps anyways, right? So why would it call your getters/setters that would just bounce back to WPF. That Getters/Setters are there **only for you** so you can set/get the values from code. WPF does not use them at all. It just checks if they exist. That;s why you need to register ChangedHandlers else where, not in Setters.

Comment: @user3565590: So.. we got to the end finally :) well, glad to be of any help :) have fun with those new tools, just remember: don't overdo! :)